# JTable cells are not updating

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I just started high school and am new at programming. I am working on my first assignment and am stuck with a problem. I have looked everywhere but have not found any help. I have written a gui that accepts input and outputs data in a JTable. Everything looks fine except that the table doesn´t update when I enter new input, ie, the date previously displayed does not change to new values. I suspect that the implementation of AbstractTableModel shown below is what´s causing the malfunction as I just don´t know how to override the methods isCellEditable and setValueAt. Can someone pls make the necessary corrections and give me any extra info that will help me finish my project? I would be deeply grateful if you could get back to me asap.

ps. nh and vh are integer arrays, proc_1 and proc_ are string arrays and the table is added to a jtabbedpane, if that matters...

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel  {
    int numRows;
    String colNames[] = { "NH", "Horse Names", "VH",
                          "Proc. I", "Proc. II" };
    TableModel()  {
        super();
        numRows = fnh;
    }   

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()  {
       return numRows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()  {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName( int c ) {
        return colNames[c];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt( int r, int c )  {
        if ( c == 0 ) 
            return nh[r];
        else if ( c == 1 )
            return hNam[r];
        else if ( c == 2 )
            return vh[r] ;
        else if ( c == 3 )
            return proc_1[r];
        else 
            return proc_2[r];    
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable( int r, int c )  {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt( Object v, int r, int c )  {
        fireTableCellUpdated( r, c );
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your DataValues? the array containing table data..!!

Comment: Great link Reimus. Will surely come in handy. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

- Your `setValueAt(...)` method sets no values in the model. All it does is fire a notification method and nothing else.
- Also your model is essentially useless as it has no data "nucleus", nothing to hold the data that its supposed to hold. Often this is a collection such as an ArrayList.
- You need to re-read the JTable tutorial, I think.

Comment: Yes, and  I don´t know how to do that, as I said.

Comment: @user2143292: read the tutorial. You can't just make this stuff up.

Comment: Have read and not understood, otherwise woudldn´t be here asking for help...?

Comment: I don´t follow. How come the table shows up the first time holding the correct output?

Comment: @user2143292: because your `getValueAt(...)` returns some data, but it is data that is held *outside* of the model, and you must change this. `getValueAt(...)` should return data that is internal to the model such as an `ArrayList<SomeType>`.

Comment: Oh, I see it. I haven´t got to the lesson on containers, though. It´s a thick chapter and I need to finish this asap not only for academic purposes but to help someone else... Any chance you could write that for me. I would gladly post the whole code on here but it is quite extensive...

Comment: @user2143292: Myself, if I needed something like this done "ASAP", I'd just use a DefaultTableModel that I've added an array of String for the columns and simply add rows by calling its `addRow(...)` method. There are plenty of examples of just this sort of thing that can be found by searching this site.

Comment: OK HFOE, let me give that a shot. Thank you kindly for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Here your `setValueAt` should look like

```
public void setValueAt( Object v, int r, int c )  {
    if ( c == 0 ) 
        nh[r] = (Integer)v;
    else if ( c == 1 )
        hNam[r] = (String)v;
    else if ( c == 2 )
        vh[r] = (Integer)v;
    else if ( c == 3 )
        proc_1[r] =(String)v;
    else 
        proc_2[r] =(String) v;
    fireTableCellUpdated( r, c );
}
```

And after your project completes. Read to complete tutorial of `JTable` at oracle official site. There you would get a complete picture of how to use `JTable` in proper way. Here is the tutorial link : [`How to use JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot Vishal. Let me give that a try and I will get back to you shortly, OK? Pls keep an eye on this posting.  :-)

Comment: Hey buddy, can you pls explain me why the table shows up the first time with the correct data? Is v an object holding the new data? How do I populate it?

Comment: First of all you tell me did this work for you ? And regarding your other question I would be able to reply them only after I see your complete code.

Comment: What Error are you getting?

Comment: By the way, thanks for the link. It looks awesome for a beginner. Will definitely use it later. If you could give me more immediate help though that would be great though  :-) I don´t get any errors.